# X11 and Open Motif libraries

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to install a quite old Fortran code requiring xorg and OpenMotif libraries.

Here is part of the install script where the code is checking for these libraries:

```
    echo -n "Esistono le librerie X11 ? ... "
    (find /usr -name lost+found -prune -name audit -prune -o -name libX11.so > /tmp/___) >& /dev/null
    set trovato=(`cat /tmp/___`)
    rm -f /tmp/___
    if( $#trovato < 1 ) then
    (find /usr -name lost+found -prune -name audit -prune -o -name 'libX11.so*' > /tmp/___) >& /dev/null
    set trovate=(`cat /tmp/___`)
    rm -f /tmp/___
    if( $#trovate < 1 ) then
    echo "ASSURDO! Non appare installato in modo corretto"
    echo "nemmeno il server X11: ERRORE CRITICISSIMO"
    echo "(sei sicuro/a di essere in inittab 5 ?)"
    else
    echo "Appare mancante la libreria  libX11.so  e tuttavia esistono "
    echo "librerie libX11.so.n.m. Eseguire (come root) un link simbolico "
    echo "della libreria opportuna a  libX11.so  e ripetere l'esecuzione "
    echo "del presente script."
    endif
    exit
    endif
    echo  "Trovate "
    echo -n "Esistono le librerie dell'Intrinsic Toolkit ? ... "
    (find /usr -name lost+found -prune -name audit -prune -o -name libXt.so > /tmp/___) >& /dev/null
    set trovato=(`cat /tmp/___`)
    rm -f cat /tmp/___
    if( $#trovato < 1 ) then
    (find /usr -name lost+found -prune -name audit -prune -o -name 'libXt.so*' > /tmp/___) >& /dev/null
    set trovate=(`cat /tmp/___`)
    rm -f cat /tmp/___
    if( $#trovate < 1 ) then
    echo " "
    echo " "
    echo "ASSURDO! Non appare installato in modo corretto"
    echo "nemmeno il server X11: ERRORE CRITICISSIMO"
    echo "(sei sicuro/a di essere in inittab 5 ?)"
    else
    echo "Appare mancante la libreria  libXt.so  e tuttavia esistono "
    echo "librerie libXt.so.n.m. Eseguire (come root) un link simbolico "
    echo "della libreria opportuna a  libXt.so  e ripetere l'esecuzione "
    echo "del presente script."
    endif
    exit
    endif
    echo  "Trovate "
    echo -n "Esistono le librerie di OpenMotif ? ... "
    set MOTIFLIB=""
    (find /usr -name lost+found -prune -name audit -prune -o -name libXm.so > /tmp/___) >& /dev/null
    set trovato=(`cat /tmp/___`)
    rm -f /tmp/___
    if( $#trovato < 1 ) then
    (find /usr -name lost+found -prune -name audit -prune -o -name 'libXm.so*' > /tmp/___) >& /dev/null
    set trovate=(`cat /tmp/___`)
    rm -f /tmp/___
    if( $#trovate < 1 ) then
    echo "No. "
    echo " "
    echo "Non appaiono installate in modo corretto le librerie di OpenMotif:"
    echo " ERRORE CRITICISSIMO: giotto NON FUNZIONA SENZA DI LORO"
    else
    echo "Appare mancante la libreria  libXm.so  e tuttavia esistono "
    echo "librerie libXm.so.n.m. Eseguire (come root) un link simbolico "
    echo "della libreria opportuna a  libXm.so  e ripetere l'esecuzione "
    echo "del presente script."
    endif
    exit
    else
    echo  "Trovate "
    set MOTIFLIB=`dirname $trovato[1]`
    endif
    if($MOTIFLIB == "") exit
    set MOTIFLIB=( -L $MOTIFLIB )
```

Ok, I know this is in Italian, and I can't even translate it properly as I speak French...

But I hope I can give an idea about the libraries dependencies.

My question is : I'm running Snow Leopard with XCode 4 installed. I have the X11 installed too.

Are the X11 libraries present ? Am I able to provide these libraries without additional installation ?

I'm even more confused about OpenMotif, so any help or suggestion to install (or find) these are welcome.

Comment: Whats stopping you from trying? You could extract each bash command run it individually (the finds) and see what you come up with, he is just writing their names to files and verifying they exist, which they probably do if you have x11 installed.

Comment: OK I should have said that what it's looking for doesn't exist, eg. I can't find any libX11.so, I have /usr/X11 path with .dylib libs but I don't know how the differences.

Comment: According to a couple of places on the web they are equivalent, but maybe not for your purposes, I have no idea. You could try to change .so to .dylib in the find sections and see if that works, *purely hypothetical.*

Comment: I can try that for the X11 libs. For Motif I don't know where to find them.

Comment: Does this mention of installing open motif work http://mattlong.posterous.com/install-xpdf-on-os-x-106-snow-leopard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted OSX uses .dylib and not .so for shared libraries.

For motif I would install this as a port via [macports](http://www.macports.org/) and get the [openmotif](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/x11/openmotif/Portfile) port. Note that macports will install a newer version of X11 from a  as well so this will take time.

then you will need a fortran compiler - note that Apple's gcc does not have Fortran as far as I understand so you will have to install that via macports as well - either a new gcc for possibly gfortran - I don't know the details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was trying to avoid macports in favor of brew. I already installed gfortran with brew but apparently there's no brew for openmotif. I'm kind of afraid that this new macports install of X11 will create a big mess. Is macports clean enough to install another X11 ?

Comment: yes - macports keeps to itself all in /opt  so is clean (as is fink) - homebrew has more chance of creating a mess as it does not separate itself out - however best not to mix them

Comment: What you're saying is pretty much the opposite of what I read about brew. Why do you say it's not separated ?

Comment: Homebrew uses the Apple libraries as much as possible. macports uses itself as much as possible. Both are affected by anything you pit locally into /usr/local - brew even more so as that is what it uses. Now how much of an issue this is I don't know. What is certain is that macports and fink are more separated than homebrew.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll install macports and install openmotif from it, as I don't (yet) have much installed with brew I hope it will be fine.